# sampling from large numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm creating a numpy array from a .npy file.  It's several gigs and I'd like to just sample from it, but I'm having a hard time getting a look at any of the data elements.  I'm new to working with .npy files, can anyone suggest how to sample from the array?  I'd like to test my code with a much smaller sampler than runs quicker.

```
code:

dataset = np.load('../'+dataset_name)

[user_train, user_validation, user_test, Item, usernum, itemnum] = dataset

dataset.shape

output:

(6,)

dataset.dtype

output:

dtype('O')
```

Comment: Tell us about `dataset`.  Specifically its `shape` and `dtype`.  Normally we don't `unpack` an array as  you are trying to do.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I've updated the original post, the .shape is (6,) and the .dtype is dtype('0').  I'm having a hard time exploring the data.  It took a long time to load and if I try to display dataset[0] it just locks my computer up.

Comment: OK, so it's a 1d array with 6 elements, which you unpack into the 6 variables.  That makes more sense.  But being object dtype, those 6 variables could be almost anything - lists, scalars, other arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah I figured out the user_train one is a dict.